# cuda 6.5 installation in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I recently upgrade the ubuntu and nvidia driver is not working anymore, and I am trying to re-install nvidia driver and cuda. Here is what I did

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/uninstall_cuda_6.5.pl

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/
```

However, it always gave me this error message:

[image]

I tried reboot but it does not work. The header is linux-headers-3.16.0-40-generic.

I looked at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log, the error is:
[image]

However, the **include/geenrated/autoconf.h** and **include/config/auto.conf** is existed in **/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-40-generic** directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing cuda 7.0